# OrientDB phpOrient socket_read()

Tags: php, web-applications, orientdb

I am using OrientDB and phpOrient to make a web application.

When connecting to OrientDB  using phpOrient , the following error will appear. That's a long reply. (Time out)

> Warning: socket_read(): unable to read from socket [10060]

This happens especially when multiple users who manage with Web application access OrientDB.

Is this a problem with setting up OrientDB or is it a problem with setting up php? Please tell me the cause and measures.

Comment: What version are you using? Thx

Comment: I'm using OrientDB Server v2.2.25